# eBot CS:GO Apache 2.4.10 Mod Rewrite does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've successfully installed following webinterface: https://github.com/deStrO/eBot-CSGO-Web

I've configured the Apache vHost as shown:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin <email>
      DocumentRoot /var/www/ebot-web/web

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

*/var/www/ebot-web/* looks like this:

```
# ls -lha /var/www/ebot-web/
total 56K
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data 4.0K Dec 26 16:27 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4.0K Dec 26 16:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3  2015 apps
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4.0K Dec 26 19:30 cache
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4.0K Dec 26 18:22 config
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4.0K Dec 26 19:30 data
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   41 Apr  3  2015 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3  2015 lib
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3  2015 plugins
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 1.1K Apr  3  2015 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  446 Apr  3  2015 symfony
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3  2015 test
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 2.1K Apr  3  2015 TODO
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data 4.0K Dec 26 19:29 web
```

*/var/www/ebot-web/web/* looks like this:

```
# ls -lha /var/www/ebot-web/web/
total 48K
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data 4.0K Dec 26 19:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data 4.0K Dec 26 16:27 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  235 Apr  3  2015 admin.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3  2015 css
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 4.7K Apr  3  2015 favicon.png
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  595 Dec 26 19:24 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3  2015 images
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3  2015 img
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  236 Apr  3  2015 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  3  2015 js
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   26 Dec 26 19:29 robots.txt
```

I'm able to visit the web interface by opening http://hostname/ and the admin backend works fine. But at the frontend I've the problem, that all URLs aren't working. I always receive following error message from my browser:

```
404 Not Found - The requested URL /credits was not found on this server.
```

All URLs are linked like this one: http://hostname/credits

Well... The site is accessible, if I open it manually with http://hostname/index.php/credits.

I think there is an issue with the .htaccess file, but I'm not sure and don't have the needed skills for.

```
/var/www/ebot-web # find . -name .htaccess
./web/.htaccess
./lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/generator/skeleton/project/web/.htaccess
```

Here is the content of the */var/www/ebot-web/web/.htaccess* file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

I've uncommented the above lines as suggested, but it didn't changed anything. The web-server log is empty, also if I enable warn log level.

The issue is, that the "index.php" is missing in the URL. But the rewrite rule should insert this, or not?

The rewrite module is enabled:

```
# a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Damn. I had to allow such changes by .htaccess in the vHost configuration. I've added this inside the vHost VirtualHost configuration:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ...
        <Directory /var/www/ebot-web/web>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        ...
    </VirtualHost>
```

Now it's working well! :)